# Remove "${anything}" from string in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove ${anything} or ${somethingelse}  from a string, but i dont find the regex.

My actual code

```
String url = http://test.com/index.jsp?profil=all&value=${value}
String regex = "\\$\\{*\\}";
url = url .replaceAll(regex, ""); // expect http://test.com/index.jsp?profil=all&value= 
//but it is http://test.com/index.jsp?profil=all&value=${value}
```

i'm sure the solution is stupid, but no way to find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one:

```
"\\$\\{.*?\\}"
```

The `.*?` matches the shortest possible string that is followed by `}`.

Comment: yeah i had to wait 15 minutes, and thx again you saved my week-end :)

Answer (score 1):

you're removing any number of `{`'s, because you have `{*` instead of `.*`

should be `\\$\\{.*\\}`

that will indeed allow anything between the braces, do you want that to be alpha only or something?

that would be `\\$\\{[a-zA-Z]*\\}`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be `\\$\\{[^\\}]*\\}` (any character different than })